# Example calculation of estimating GMM parameters using EM

Tags: statistics, optimization, normal-distribution, expectation

I'm trying to study expectation maximization and I've almost got the idea. What I'm missing is a concrete example. Could someone familiar with the subject give me a concrete example how one would apply expectation maximization algorithm for Gaussian mixture models?

I have tried to google for examples, but it seems to be difficult to find a good one. Could you show all the theoretical steps and then apply the steps with a numerical example? You don't need to repeat the algorithm for many iterations, one is enough :)

If this question is too long to answer might someone give me references where I could find a good and clear examples?

Thnx for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/350/lectures/29/lecture-29.pdf) is a quick reference to mixture models and EM: it is helpful to fix notation and it describes the link between EM and k-means.
[Here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~radford/ftp/emk.pdf), at paragraph 4 you can find an example involving Gaussian mixtures with some computations involving sampling and subsequent outcome analysis.

If you are interested also in generalized linear *mixture* models, please have a look at  chapter 3 of this [book](http://books.google.ch/books/about/Simulation_based_Econometric_Methods.html?id=k5jF-7VRMnEC&redir_esc=y): there is a description of likelihood inference *via* EM, numerical simulations and sampling.